# Altering views from inherited class

Tags: android, layout, view, android-context

I'm not new to Android, self taught - but I may have missed this in my training.

I had my app set up all nice but have now decided to implement a Spinner into a custom title bar. Basically, I have a main class in my project which extends Activity, the other Activity classes of my application extends this class to create a parent class which handles a number of objects throughout the app, for example the Spinner on my custom title bar etc, and the Spinner calls back to the parent class to handle the selections.

I am trying to call a method inside one of the Activitys from an if/else statement of my Spinner which for example sets text to a view in one of the Activity classes but it throws a NPE on the line with the view.

(listArray is the adapter for the Spinner, defined earlier in the code, decider is the returned name of the item selected)

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            String decider = listArray.get(arg2);

            if (decider.equalsIgnoreCase("Example") {
                new OtherClass().createFile(view, _context, s);
            } else if (decider.equalsIgnoreCase("Example 2") {
                do this...
            }

}

private void createFile(View view, Context context, String s) {
    Log.d("method:", "createFile, active");
    addRecipeIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.addRecipeIcon);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) addRecipeIcon.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
}
```

```
02-17 14:40:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 14:40:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2099): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 14:40:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(2099): at com.example.example.OtherClass.createFile(OtherClass.java:633)
```

What I'm asking is how can I access ImageViews, TextViews etc from methods called within this class that relate to the specific Activitys, I've tried passing the view as a parameter and finding the ImageView from that but it still returns null. I've redone some of the code here but it's just the concept I'm after

Sorry if I'm just being slow here, really stuck!

Comment: your question is not clear can you pls elaborate what you mean by specific activity and which activity has ImageView?

Comment: Each activity extends this parent class from which the spinner (available to all activities) is defined and managed, the ImageView lies in the OtherClass activity. How can I access the view from the parent activity? Do I need to pass in context every time?